# Как проверить поддержку TUN в VPS на OpenVZ?

Tags: linux, vps, openvz

На одном сайте есть такая информация:

> Для работы OpenVPN требуется поддержка TUN/TAP. Поэтому для OpenVPN
>   подходят не все типы виртуализации VPS/VDS. Hапример, подходит KVM и
>   не подходит OpenVZ. Хотя в OpenVZ и существует возможность включения
>   TUN/TAP устройств, но не все хостинг-провайдеры ее предоставляют. Это
>   лучше уточнить заранее, перед оформлением услуги.
>
> Поддержку TUN проверяют командой ls -l /dev/net/tun, вывод будет
>   примерно такой:
>
> ```
> ls -l /dev/net/tun
> crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 200 Sep 27 03:31 /dev/net/tun
> ```

Мой вывод данной команды выглядит следующим образом:

```
root@s2e24dbab:~# ls -l /dev/net/tun ls: cannot access '/dev/net/tun':
No such file or directory
```

Означает ли это, что хостинг-провайдер не включил поддержку TUN/TAP устройств для моего VPS?

Т.к. я хочу настроить OpenVPN, мне ведь обязательно нужна поддержка TUN, иначе нет смысла возиться с подключением?

Comment: Почему просто у хостера не спросить?

Comment: Хостер сам не шарит.
У него на других VPS всё норм, а на моей почему-то с tun такие проблемы и nat нет

Comment: В этом случае, стОит задуматься о смене хостера. А по теме, вот же написано как это проверять в wiki у openvz: https://wiki.openvz.org/VPN_via_the_TUN/TAP_device

Comment: @ДмитрийЧубаров если нет добавте http://www.naturalborncoder.com/virtualization/2014/10/17/understanding-tun-tap-interfaces/

Comment: @nobody, там написано о том, как добавить tun к контейнеру, а как проверить его наличие из контейнера информации нет (сменить хоста невозможно)